# Cannot install PyQt5

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

While I am trying to install PyQt5 using this command:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpctfd62ms
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-k0kmhb2p/pyqt5_60049985924945cb9d20fc0edf03bba9
    Complete output (37 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/bin/qmake -query
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 131, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        config_settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 479, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 79, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 225, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 75, in apply_user_defaults
        self._get_qt_configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 475, in _get_qt_configuration
        for line in project.read_command_pipe([self.qmake, '-query']):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-a0mhy5es/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 443, in read_command_pipe
        "'{0}' failed returning {1}".format(cmd, pipe.returncode))
    sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpctfd62ms Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Are you trying to install as normal user instead of root?

Comment: sorry I am still new to linux, How could it affect and how can I fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your answer to show your research efforts

Comment: execute: `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `sudo python -m pip install pyqt5`